# lapply in R , cannot open connection?

Tags: r, lapply

Here is my code:

```
library(DBI)
library(proto)
library(chron)
library(RSQLite)
library(sqldf)

setwd("C:/Users/Rachael/Desktop")# set directory to desktop

files = list.files(path = "C:/Users/Rachael/Documents" ,pattern = ".csv")

(files) # show filenames in the working directory

rdf=lapply(files, read.csv) # files are loaded into rdf
```

Here is the error message

```
(files) # show filenames in the working directory
[1] "PIR.csv"  "TWTR.csv"
rdf=lapply(files, read.csv) # files are loaded into rdf
```

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'PIR.csv': No such file or directory

What does it mean by "cannot open the connection"? Also PIR.csv was found when I showed my files, so why does it come up as no such file later on?

Comment: You set the working directory to `Desktop` but the files are in `Documents`.

Comment: You `setwd` to `...Desktop` but then  get a list of files from `...Documents`. So you are attempting to get `PIR.CSV` (which is in `Documents`) from `Desktop`, which is why the error. Try adding `full.names = TRUE` to `list.files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at your file path with the `getwd()` command. Often times, individuals forget that the `read.csv` command reads based on the current working directory. A good way around this issue in the future is to generate an absolute file path name.